# What state does "being overwhelmed" actually imply?

Tags: word-meaning

Does the state of **being overwhelmed** actually tend to express physical or emotional fatigue? or it could be both?

Comment: Have you checked any dictionaries? If not, please take a look and see if your question can be answered that way first. See our *help* pages under "Asking."

Comment: It could be used to express either one, but I think it's most often associated with mental stress.

Comment: @JimReynolds: Have you tried to analyze this case using my perspective as a non-native speaker? Thank you!

Comment: @Student - I agree with Jim. This question at least needs some mention of what you found in the dictionary. [This dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overwhelm) shows at least two different usages, as does [this one](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=overwhelm). So, clearly, the answer to your "Could it be both?" question is: _Yes, it could be both._

Comment: @J.R. Pardon me, are you a linguistic?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a cause - effect relationship, *i.e.*: "suffering fatigue or feeling worn out as a result of having been overwhelmed by something or someone", then *being overwhelmed* expresses both a physical condition and a psychological one.

Indeed, according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/overwhelm), the verb *overwhelm* has different meanings:

- as referred to a **physical condition**, as a synonym of *to defeat*:

  > to ​defeat someone or something by using a lot of ​force: *Government ​troops have overwhelmed the ​rebels and ​seized ​control of the ​capital.*

  Also, from [Urban Dictionary](http://overwhelmed.urbanup.com/675139):

  > being drunk; drinking: 
  >   *Last night i was overwhelmed.*
- As referred to an **emotive condition**, with the verb mainly used at its passive form (*to be overwhelmed*):

  > to ​cause someone to ​feel​ sudden ​strong ​emotion: *They were overwhelmed with/by ​grief when ​their​baby ​died.*

  With the same meaning of the verb (used as an adjective), there's a sentence in one of the masterpieces of the LA progressive rock band Tool, *[Roseta Stoned](https://youtu.be/VZXJLQntCP0)*, that says:

  > «*Overwhelmed* as one would be placed in my position 
  >   Such a heavy burden now to be the one»,

  but you should listen to the song to find out why he's feeling this way ( ;) ).
- A third, literal, meaning (not normally used to refer to a human condition) is related to the action of water:

  > If ​water overwhelms a ​place, it ​covers it ​suddenly and ​completely.

  This is more related to the [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=overwhelm) of the verb:

  > early 14c., "to turn upside down, to overthrow," from *over-* + Middle English *whelmen* "to turn upside down" (see whelm). Meaning "to submerge completely" is mid-15c. Perhaps the connecting notion is a boat, etc., washed over, and overset, by a big wave. Figurative sense of "to bring to ruin" is attested from 1520s.